# Regular Expression - Get Strings Before and After First Spaced Hyphen

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I know this can be done via string splitting but I'm actually interested in the regex solution for this. Basically, I would like to retrieve the entire string before and after a spaced hyphen (" - "). I've tried:

```
^[^-]*
```

And this works for strings like

```
EK725 - London to Paris
```

But once there is a non-spaced hyphen like

```
EK-725 - London to Paris
```

It breaks down. Using `^[^ - ]*` also does not seem to work. Also, I am not sure what the syntax would be to retrieve the text after the spaced hyphen. What would be the solution?

Comment: If your format is always have spaces surrounding the hyphen you want to split on - put spaces around `-` in your pattern.

Comment: `^(.+) - (.+)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
(^.+(?= - ))|((?<= - ).+$)
```

Check a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifQeNt/1)

Answer (score 2):

To get the strings before and after the *First Spaced Hyphen* you can use 2 capture groups, and match a space hyphen space:

```
^(.*?) - (.*)
```

If you want to capture at least 1 characater, change the `.*` to `.+` but note that the `.` can also match just a space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5MOUSt/1)

---

If there can be more than 1 spaces without matching newlines:

```
^(.*?)[\p{Zs}\t]+-[\p{Zs}\t]+(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jWHSq9/1)

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
[a-zA-Z]+([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))? - ([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+)
```

Really neat tool with a GUI if you want to try it yourself.
https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/

Comment: This assumes much about the range of strings that should match that the OP never specified.